# How to get some segment data of activated route? [Angular 6]

Tags: angular6, angular-activatedroute

I want to get data of activated route by segment to check if it's `company_id !== null`:

```
/company_type/company_name/company_id/some_page
```

I tried `const prefix = this.activatedRoute.url;`. But it's giving long data. I want to get segment data of `company_id`.

Thank you if you provide any answer guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('company_id');
```

By this way you can get data, but I think you can't check if it's null, because if it is null it should means that your url should be something like this:

company_type/company_name//some_page

and this url does not match declared route path.

A possible solution is to well manage route paths or to pass parameters by different ways.
Alternatively you could do something like this:

company_type/company_name/null/some_page

but I don't know how much it can be useful